# mix deps.get: Hex got installed into wrong elixir version

Tags: elixir

This is my first time using the command:

```
$ mix deps.get
```

This was the output:

```
Could not find Hex, which is needed to build dependency :ecto
Shall I install Hex? (if running non-interactively, use "mix local.hex --force") [Yn] Y
* creating /Users/7stud/.kiex/mix/archives/elixir-1.4.1/hex-0.18.1
Resolving Hex dependencies...
Dependency resolution completed:
New:
  connection 1.0.4
  db_connection 1.1.3
  decimal 1.5.0
  ecto 2.2.10
  poolboy 1.5.1
  postgrex 0.13.5
* Getting ecto (Hex package)
* Getting postgrex (Hex package)
* Getting connection (Hex package)
* Getting db_connection (Hex package)
* Getting decimal (Hex package)
* Getting poolboy (Hex package)


~/elixir_programs/friends$ iex
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Interactive Elixir (1.6.6) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)
iex(1)> 

^C$ which iex
/Users/7stud/.asdf/shims/iex

$ which elixir
/Users/7stud/.asdf/shims/elixir

$ asdf current
elixir         1.6.6   (set by /Users/7stud/.tool-versions)
erlang         20.3    (set by /Users/7stud/.tool-versions)

$ asdf list elixir
1.6.6

$ asdf list erlang
20.3
```

I installed `otp 20.3` and `elixir 1.6.6` with the `asdf` package manager:

```
^C$ which iex
/Users/7stud/.asdf/shims/iex

$ which elixir
/Users/7stud/.asdf/shims/elixir

$ asdf current
elixir         1.6.6   (set by /Users/7stud/.tool-versions)
erlang         20.3    (set by /Users/7stud/.tool-versions)

$ asdf list elixir
1.6.6

$ asdf list erlang
20.3
```

I don't care what package manager I use.  How can I make sure things like Hex are installed in elixir 1.6.6?  I can't even find elixir 1.4.1 on my system:

```
$ elixir -v
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Elixir 1.6.6 (compiled with OTP 19)
```

so how did the Hex installer find elixir 1.4.1?

If I remove the lines in my `.bash_profile` that install the `asdf shims`, and then I open a new terminal window, this is what I get:

```
~$ which elixir
/Users/7stud/.kiex/elixirs/elixir-1.4.1/bin/elixir

~$ which mix
/Users/7stud/.kiex/elixirs/elixir-1.4.1/bin/mix
~$
```

I searched google for `.kiex`, and it looks like I must have installed the `kiex` version manager for elixir at some point.

There were also some lines in my `.bash_profile` that installed `kiex` shims. I commented out the lines for `kiex` and uncommented the lines for the `asdf` shims, and I opened a new terminal window, and I tried the mix command again:

```
$mix deps.get 
Could not find Hex, which is needed to build dependency :ecto
Shall I install Hex? (if running non-interactively, use "mix local.hex --force") [Yn] Y
* creating /Users/7stud/.asdf/installs/elixir/1.6.6/.mix/archives/hex-0.18.1
Resolving Hex dependencies...
Dependency resolution completed:
Unchanged:
  connection 1.0.4
  db_connection 1.1.3
  decimal 1.5.0
  ecto 2.2.10
  poolboy 1.5.1
  postgrex 0.13.5
All dependencies up to date
```

Success.

Next problem:

```
~/elixir_programs/friends$ mix exto.gen.repo -r Friends.Repo
==> connection
Compiling 1 file (.ex)
Generated connection app
==> friends
Could not find "rebar", which is needed to build dependency :poolboy
I can install a local copy which is just used by Mix
Shall I install rebar? (if running non-interactively, use "mix local.rebar --force") [Yn]
```

But, in another terminal window:

```
$ which rebar
/usr/local/bin/rebar

~$ rebar --version
rebar 2.6.4 19 20170625_072305 git 2.6.4-6-g2a52f60

~$ which rebar3
/usr/local/bin/rebar3

~$ rebar3 --version
rebar 3.0.0-beta.4+build.3189.ref21ae314 on Erlang/OTP 20 Erts 9.3
```

So, why can't mix find my rebar?

Comment: What's the output of `which mix`?

Comment: @AdamMillerchip, `~$ which mix` =>
/Users/7stud/.asdf/shims/mix

Comment: @AdamMillerchip, I found elixir 1.4.1.  I added some more info to the bottom of my question.

Comment: @AdamMillerchip, There were also some lines in my .bash_profile that installed kiex shims.  I commented out the lines for kiex and uncommented the lines for the asdf shims, then `$mix deps.get` produced: *could not find Hex, which is needed to build dependency :ecto
Shall I install Hex? (if running non-interactively, use "mix local.hex --force") [Yn] Y
* creating /Users/7stud/.asdf/installs/elixir/1.6.6/.mix/archives/hex-0.18.1*, so I'm in business.

Comment: Great. Looks like you worked it out, I posted an answer anyway ;-)

Answer (score 1):

From your comments, it looks like `kiex` is conflicting with `asdf`.

Remove the references to `kiex` from your `.bash_profile`, and the `asdf` shims should work correctly.

Comment: I posted a new problem at the bottom of my question.

Comment: Is your `MIX_REBAR` environment variable set? https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/1b152f2656ac2f529e3dd6695ee2de2d49460c96/lib/mix/lib/mix/rebar.ex#L13 Anyway if you are using ASDF, it's probably better to avoid using the system version and let mix handle it. You can install mix's local copy with `mix local.rebar` or just allow it to install when prompted as in your example.